# Unexpected token ILLEGAL while creating table dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a table dynamically , but when i am doing it so i am getting in the browser console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/3617/

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
           var html = '<table id="myTable">\
        <thead>\
      <tr>\
         <th   width="1%"></th>\
         <th    width="18.8%">Name </th>\
         <th     width="18.8%">Difference</th>\
         <th     width="18.8%">Quantity</th>\
         <th   width="18.8%">Volumne</th>\
         <th   width="10%">Open</th>
      </tr>\
   </thead>\
   <tbody id="positivebody"></tbody>\
</table>' ;
          $(tab).html(html);
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: You have left backslash in your last "th"
http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/3618/

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a `\` after `<th   width="10%">Open</th>`

this should be   `<th   width="10%">Open</th>\`